# Fraunhofer diffraction integral in polar coordinates

Tags: optics, fourier-transform, diffraction

I want to obtain the diffraction pattern in the focal plane produced by an input Gaussian with waist $\omega$ and a phase disk with radius R and offset $\pi$, i.e. of an input field

$$E_i(\rho) = A_0 e^{-(\rho^2/\omega^2)}\times e^{i\phi(\rho)}$$
with $$
\phi(\rho) = 
\begin{cases}
\pi , & \rho \leq R \\
0,  & \text{else}
\end{cases}
$$

Since this is rotationally symmetric, I use the [polar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fraunhofer_diffraction_equation) representation of this integral to get the electric field in the focal plane:

$$
E_f(r) \propto \int_0^{\infty} d\rho \rho E_i(\rho) J_0\left(\frac{2\pi\rho r}{\lambda f}\right)
$$
where $J_0$ is the Bessel function of the first kind.
I can split the radial integral in two to get rid of the phase and obtain

$$
E_f(r) \propto -2 \int_0^R d\rho \rho e^{-\frac{\rho^2}{\omega^2}}  J_0\left(\frac{2\pi\rho r}{\lambda f}\right) + \int_0^{\infty}  d\rho \rho e^{-\frac{\rho^2}{\omega^2} } J_0\left(\frac{2\pi\rho r}{\lambda f}\right)
$$

However, I don't know how to go on from here. Any help is appreciated.